# Displaying a C# control through XSLT

Tags: c#, xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there a way to display a C# control through XSLT?

I'm trying a lot to handle this but am not able to pass the values to the control.

Below is the sample which am trying to render it out..

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;Control:Content runat="server" contenttype="&lt;xsl:value-of select="subnode/text()"/&gt;" /&gt;</xsl:text>
```

Here control should generate as shown: For the param "contenttype" value should pass dynamically...

```
<Control:Content runat="server" contenttype="ABC123" />
```

Please help me.

Comment: Good question, +1. Remember that DOE is almost never necessary and should be avoided whenever possible, as it breaks the XSLT architectural model.

Comment: What are you going to do with the result of the transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't need (and it is always a good idea to avoid using) DOE for this**.

Here is a neat solution, just using `<xsl:output method="text">`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:text>&lt;Control:Content runat="server" contenttype="</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="/subnode"/>
  <xsl:text>" /&gt;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<subnode>html</subnode>
```

**the wanted, correct output is produced**:

```
<Control:Content runat="server" contenttype="html" />
```

Comment: Thats great Dimitre.. Works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

We're using this technique at work, however, we convert the control to xml first then we use xslt to render it in the page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my scenario, it won't works this way. Since content is already published to XML & this can't be handled at this point. So while XML is rendering then i should handle that by passing the value to the control & display on the page.